# Regular expression for specific phrase with constant string

Tags: python, regex, python-3.x

Looking to down case a specific phrase within my python string using regular expression.

I currently run a for loop to run through a long series of strings following a similar format. See the code below:

```
import re
for x in range(len(out_lines)):
    test = str(out_lines[x])
    out_lines[x] = re.sub(r"(name='([.*?])')", lambda m: m.group(1).lower(), test)
```

The out_lines variable is a list of strings following the same format as shown below:

```
<column caption='Subordination' datatype='string' name='[SUBORDINATE]' role='dimension' type='nominal' />
<column caption='Issuer' datatype='string' name='[ISSUER_NAME]' role='dimension' type='nominal' />
```

The ideal outcome is for the string within the brackets of the `name='[*str*]'` arg to be down cased for example.

```
<column caption='Subordination' datatype='string' name='[subordinate]' role='dimension' type='nominal' />
<column caption='Issuer' datatype='string' name='[issuer_name]' role='dimension' type='nominal' />
```

But the whole string cannot be down cased because other args might have capitalized letters, and those need to stay...

I believe that my issue is due to an incorrect regex expression...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to escape the square brackets in the regexp, since square brackets have special meaning.

```
out_lines[x] = re.sub(r"name='\[(.*?)\]'", lambda m: "name='[" + m.group(1).lower() + "]'", test)
```

And you don't need a capture group around the whole regexp, just around the part inside the brackets.

Comment: This works perfectly for downcasing the specific section, however it removes the `name='[abc]'` see this output: `<column caption='Location' datatype='string' management_location role='dimension' type='nominal' />` where the expected output is  `<column caption='Location' datatype='string' name='[management_location]' role='dimension' type='nominal' />`is there a way to just hard code this string back in? @Barmar

Comment: I added the `name='[...]'` part in the lambda.